# How do I configure Automapper to post data to multiple related tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

I want to post data to multiple tables that are related via navigation properties.  I'm using Automapper to do this, however, I am getting an empty row whenever I submit data so I think my configuration or approach could be wrong.

I have three tables which are represented by a ViewModel, here is my code:

**BaseEntity.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class BaseEntity
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CreatedUser { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedUser { get; set; }
        public string DeletedUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Car.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Car : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Reg { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Options> Options { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Spec> Spec { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Options.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Options : BaseEntity
    {
        public bool? Stereo { get; set; }
        public bool? FogLights { get; set; }
        public bool? BikeRack { get; set; }

        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Spec.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Spec : BaseEntity
    {
        public int? BHP { get; set; }
        public string EngineCode { get; set; }
        public string? Displacement { get; set; }

        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this.

**CarViewModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyProject.Data.ViewModels
{
    public class VesselViewModel
    {
        //Car
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Reg { get; set; }

        //Options
        public bool? Stereo { get; set; }
        public bool? FogLights { get; set; }
        public bool? BikeRack { get; set; }

        //Spec
        public int? BHP { get; set; }
        public string EngineCode { get; set; }
        public string? Displacement { get; set; }    

        //Navigation Property
        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MappingConfiguration/CarProfile.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;
using MyProject.Data;
using MyProject.Data.ViewModels;

namespace MyProject.UI.MappingConfigurations
{
    public class CarProfile : Profile
    {
        public CarProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Car, CarViewModel>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

**MappingConfiguration/MakeProfile.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;
using MyProject.Data;
using MyProject.Data.ViewModels;

namespace MyProject.UI.MappingConfigurations
{
    public class MakeProfile : Profile
    {
        public OptionsProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Options, OptionsViewModel>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

**MappingConfiguration/SpecProfile.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;
using MyProject.Data;
using MyProject.Data.ViewModels;

namespace MyProject.UI.MappingConfigurations
{
    public class SpecProfile : Profile
    {
        public SpecProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Spec, CarViewModel>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my 'Create' method that uses Automapper to do all of this.  As a note, I'm using a generic repository for my work with dependency injection and a service layer.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CarViewModel car) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var carData = _mapper.Map<Car>(car);
        var optionsData = _mapper.Map<Options>(car);
        var specData = _mapper.Map<Spec>(car);

        _carService.InsertCar(carData);
        _optionsService.InsertOptions(optionsData);
        _specService.InsertSpec(specData);

        return View();
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Form**

This is where the data is submitted, due to the related data, a ViewModel is used for the sake of the UI.

```
Models.VesselViewModel

<form id="carCreateForm" asp-controller="Car" asp-action="Create" method="post" asp-antiforgery="true" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...form inputs here.
</form>
```

When a new car is added, the related data is posted but an empty 'Car' is added to the 'Car' table.  What is wrong with my configuration? Any help is appreciated.